# Facing Redis connectivity issue in the sitecore docker container

Tags: docker, redis

I am facing the following error while establishing a connection with Redis in the docker container.

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Timeout 
performing GET (2000ms), inst: 0, qu: 1, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: 
SpinningDown, rs: NotStarted, ws: Idle, in: 0, last-in: 0, cur-in: 
0, serverEndpoint: 127.0.0.1:6379, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 
available, clientName: 3E4085DCE28F(SE.Redis-v2.6.80.25426), IOCP: 
(Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: 
(Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=47,Max=32767), v: 2.6.80.25426 (Please take 
a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can 
cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)","Excepti onType":"StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException","StackTrace":"   at 
StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server, T defaultValue) in` /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1876\r\n   at 
StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor``1 processor, ServerEndPoint server, T defaultValue) in 
/__/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisBase.cs:line 62\r\n   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.StringGet(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags)
```

Do you have any ideas on how this issue can be resolved?

Containers running in my local,

[image]

Making redis connection from `CM(xp0)=>Redis(XP1)`.

Comment: Try to add `sslprotocols=tls12` to your Redis connection string.